# Add options to select in Preline

Tags: javascript, select

I have an issue with Preline UI, I am trying to use the advanced select.
I have this html:

```
<div class="relative">
                    <select multiple data-hs-select='{
                      "placeholder": "Select multiple options...",
                      "toggleTag": "<button type=\"button\"></button>",
                      "toggleClasses": "hs-select-disabled:pointer-events-none hs-select-disabled:opacity-50 relative py-3 px-4 pe-9 flex text-nowrap w-full cursor-pointer bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg text-start text-sm focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 before:absolute before:inset-0 before:z-[1] dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600",
                      "dropdownClasses": "mt-2 z-50 w-full max-h-72 p-1 space-y-0.5 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg overflow-hidden overflow-y-auto dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700",
                      "optionClasses": "py-2 px-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-800 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-slate-900 dark:hover:bg-slate-800 dark:text-gray-200 dark:focus:bg-slate-800",
                      "optionTemplate": "<div class=\"flex justify-between items-center w-full\"><span data-title></span><span class=\"hidden hs-selected:block\"><svg class=\"flex-shrink-0 size-3.5 text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500\" xmlns=\"http:.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\" viewBox=\"0 0 24 24\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"currentColor\" stroke-width=\"2\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\"><polyline points=\"20 6 9 17 4 12\"/></svg></span></div>"
                    }' class="hidden" id="copyProfileProductSelect">
                        
                    </select>

                    <div class="absolute top-1/2 end-3 -translate-y-1/2">
                        <svg class="flex-shrink-0 size-3.5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path d="m7 15 5 5 5-5"/><path d="m7 9 5-5 5 5"/></svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

That is the select itself, which seems to be working fine.
But I need to be able to dynamically add options depending on other factors in my code.

So i have this js :

```
const select = window.HSSelect.getInstance(document.getElementById("copyProfileProductSelect"), true);
            // select.clear();
            console.log("select instance", select);
            // Add products to select
            products.forEach(product => {
                select.addOption([
                {
                    title: product.name,
                    val: product.id
                }]);
            })
```

Which according to the docs on preline https://preline.co/plugins/html/advanced-select.html
Should add an option to the select.

But I keep getting
*'select.addOption is not a function'*

Anybody have any tips or insight?

This is my select when console.log.

```
{
    "id": "copyProfileProductSelect",
    "element": {
        "el": {
            "0": {}
        },
        "options": {
            "placeholder": "Select multiple options...",
            "toggleTag": "<button type=\"button\"></button>",
            "toggleClasses": "hs-select-disabled:pointer-events-none hs-select-disabled:opacity-50 relative py-3 px-4 pe-9 flex text-nowrap w-full cursor-pointer bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg text-start text-sm focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 before:absolute before:inset-0 before:z-[1] dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600",
            "dropdownClasses": "mt-2 z-50 w-full max-h-72 p-1 space-y-0.5 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg overflow-hidden overflow-y-auto dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700",
            "optionClasses": "py-2 px-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-800 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-slate-900 dark:hover:bg-slate-800 dark:text-gray-200 dark:focus:bg-slate-800",
            "optionTemplate": "<div class=\"flex justify-between items-center w-full\"><span data-title></span><span class=\"hidden hs-selected:block\"><svg class=\"flex-shrink-0 size-3.5 text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500\" xmlns=\"http:.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\" viewBox=\"0 0 24 24\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"currentColor\" stroke-width=\"2\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\"><polyline points=\"20 6 9 17 4 12\"/></svg></span></div>"
        },
        "events": {},
        "value": [],
        "placeholder": "Select multiple options...",
        "hasSearch": false,
        "mode": "default",
        "viewport": null,
        "isOpened": false,
        "isMultiple": true,
        "isDisabled": false,
        "toggleTag": "<button type=\"button\"></button>",
        "toggleClasses": "hs-select-disabled:pointer-events-none hs-select-disabled:opacity-50 relative py-3 px-4 pe-9 flex text-nowrap w-full cursor-pointer bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg text-start text-sm focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 before:absolute before:inset-0 before:z-[1] dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600",
        "toggleCountText": null,
        "toggleCountTextMinItems": 1,
        "tagsClasses": null,
        "tagsItemTemplate": null,
        "tagsItemClasses": null,
        "tagsInputClasses": null,
        "dropdownTag": null,
        "dropdownClasses": "mt-2 z-50 w-full max-h-72 p-1 space-y-0.5 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg overflow-hidden overflow-y-auto dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700",
        "dropdownDirectionClasses": null,
        "dropdownSpace": 10,
        "searchWrapperTemplate": null,
        "searchWrapperClasses": "bg-white p-2 sticky top-0",
        "searchClasses": "block w-[calc(100%-2rem)] text-sm border-gray-200 rounded-md focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 py-2 px-3 my-2 mx-4",
        "searchPlaceholder": "Search...",
        "searchNoResultText": "No options found...",
        "searchNoResultClasses": "px-4 text-sm",
        "optionTemplate": "<div class=\"flex justify-between items-center w-full\"><span data-title></span><span class=\"hidden hs-selected:block\"><svg class=\"flex-shrink-0 size-3.5 text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500\" xmlns=\"http:.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\" viewBox=\"0 0 24 24\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"currentColor\" stroke-width=\"2\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\"><polyline points=\"20 6 9 17 4 12\"/></svg></span></div>",
        "optionTag": null,
        "optionClasses": "py-2 px-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-800 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-slate-900 dark:hover:bg-slate-800 dark:text-gray-200 dark:focus:bg-slate-800",
        "descriptionClasses": null,
        "iconClasses": null,
        "isAddTagOnEnter": true,
        "animationInProcess": false,
        "selectOptions": [],
        "wrapper": {},
        "toggleTextWrapper": {},
        "toggle": {},
        "dropdown": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: So what does the log of `select` to the console show?

Comment: Added it as an edit

Comment: And when you log it from inside your `products.forEach` callback function - still the same?

Comment: Its a foreach nothing will change between that.

Comment: The examples in the documentation vary, in whether they are passing `true` as second parameter to the `HSSelect.getInstance` method. What happens when you try without?

Comment: Now i get the options!